# Unable to update already cached list using @CachePut

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I am using `redis cache` in `spring boot` application. Requirement is - We need data list on certain date filter. So to achieve that I used `cacheable` annotation.

Now when I run it for first time, it fetches records from db. When run multiple times it returns data stored in `cache`. Perfect! till here it is running fine.

Then I make an entry in `db` using my `jpa repository`, with `CachePut` annotation.

Now, assuming that I will again get the cache data with updated entry, I make a request to my `GET` api which I tried above. But to my surprise it fails to execute. Forget about the latest entry, this time it didn't even show earlier cached data list also.

```
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "custDetails", key="#newApplicationDate")
    @Override
    public List<FetchResponse> fetchAll2(String newApplicationDate) {
        //some code to return list
    }


@CachePut(cacheNames = "custDetails", key="#strDate")
@Override
public CustomerDetail updateCustomer(CustomerDetail customerDetail,String strDate) {
    CustomerDetail customerDetail2 =  custRepository.saveAndFlush(customerDetail);
    return customerDetail2;
}
```

I crossed check using print statements, both `newApplicationDate` and `strDate` date values are same.

In `redis client` I checked `keys *` it showed something like:

```
1) "custDetails:\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\n2023-11-01"
```

and in spring boot console I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.model.CustomerDetail cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at com.myapp.service.MyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$347be321.fetchAll2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
```

How can I update the existing `cached` list using `cachePut` annotation?

=========================================

I also tried below code i.e. calling a same return type method again, this time I put the `cachePut` annotation now in this new method:

```
@Override
public CustomerDetail updateCustomer(CustomerDetail customerDetail,String strDate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("!!!!!  "+strDate+"   !!!!!");
    CustomerDetail customerDetail2 =  custRepository.saveAndFlush(customerDetail);
    if(customerDetail2!=null) {
        refreshCache(strDate);
    }
    return customerDetail2;
}
@CachePut(cacheNames = "custDetails", key="#strDate")   
public List<FetchResponse> refreshCache(String strDate){
    return ekycService.fetchAll2(strDate);
}
```

But no success..

=================UPDATE================

Now I have put both `Cacheable` and `CachePut` in same service class.

```
@Cacheable(value = "custDetails", key = "#date")
    @Override
    public List<CustomerDetail> fetchByDate(String date) {

        return custRepository.findByCreateDatess(date);
        
    }

@CachePut(value = "custDetails", key="#strDate")    
    @Override
    public CustomerDetail updateCustomer(CustomerDetail customerDetail,String strDate) {
        CustomerDetail customerDetail2 =  custRepository.saveAndFlush(customerDetail);
        return customerDetail2;
    }
```

Again same issue. When I try adding `CustomerDetail` to the `List<CustomerDetail>` , then onwards I am not getting List. I am getting below error instead when trying to get `List<CustomerDetail>`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.model.CustomerDetail cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

If caching can not sync with its own existing list, then why on earth it is so talked about concept!

Comment: The problem is the value of the `date` key is the `CustomerDetail` and not a list of them, ensure the `fetchByDate()` method has correct signature

Comment: @WildDev On given date, there could be multiple customers created. We need list of customers created on given date. Can't I cache the list? and then update the same ? If no then what's the use of caching.

Comment: To store a list you need either iterate over it and persist each the element individually or save the entire list instance by a key. In your example the `fetchByDate()` is trying to put the `List` instance to the regular customer cache. Since it's different datatype, it might not work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WildDev explained in his comment above, the return types of the value to cache must match for a given key when using a specifically "named" cache.

In your examples, this would equate to:

```java
@Service
class CacheableCustomerServiceExample {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="customerDetails")
    List<CustomerDetail> fetchByDate(String date) {
        // ...
    }

    @CachePut(cacheNames="customerDetails", key="#date")
    List<CustomerDetail> updateCustomer(String date, CustomerDetail customer) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Remember, your "*customerDetails*" cache will have the following entry after the `fetchByDate(..)` service method is called:

```
KEY  | VALUE
------------
date | List<CustomerDetail>
```

This means you need logic in your `updateCustomer(..)` service method to update the `List` of `CustomerDetail` objects returned by the update method to subsequently update the cache entry for the "date" key.

> WARNING: Keep in mind, you cannot simply call the `fetchByDate(..)` service method from inside the service proxy, as this won't invoke Spring's caching AOP logic, for reasons explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/core/aop/proxying.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Arguably, if any `CustomerDetail` entry in the `List` is updated then the cache entry should be invalidated. Therefore, your `updateCustomer(..)` method would rather be:

```java
@CacheEvict(cacheNames="customerDetails", key="#date")
CustomerDetail updateCustomer(String date, CustomerDetail customer) {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, the service method return types don't need to match.

Yes, this will remove the cached `List` entirely, but the next time the particular date is requested on fetch (i.e. `fetchByDate(..)`), then the `List` can be lazily reloaded/cached.

This approach might come at the expense of more latency, but consume less memory.

Also, you need to consider how frequently individual `CustomerDetail` objects stored in the cache `List` are updated, in addition to the "concurrency" of the updates. You may possibly run into race conditions with your current arrangement, without some form of synchronization (for [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/integration/cache/annotations.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-synchronized)), especially, if your `List` of `CustomerDetail` objects are large in size and the concurrency and frequency of updates are high. This in itself defeats the purpose of caching.

Other things to consider is if some other application is updating the backend data source outside of this application using caching. There are many things to think about, technically.

> TIP: You typically only want to cache non-highly transactional data (non-frequently changing data) that is computationally expense to create or expensive to retrieve (e.g. network bound data, such as calling some Web service, like a REST API), but referred to often.

Personally, I'd prefer to cache individual objects and not collections of those objects. However, if you are caching a collection, then I'd argue to 1) keep the `List` of things related and 2) small.

There are several ways to handle what you want to do in your case, but I present 1 way here.

> WARNING: This approach is not necessarily the best way, and it depends on the use case, requirements and SLAs for your application.

See the example [test](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/cached-collection/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingCollectionOfObjectsIntegrationTests.java#L75-L105) I wrote for this post.

Comment: I got your point Sir John. Caching should be used on individual entities. Not on collection . And if it is so much needed, then we should use cacheEvict to refresh the entire list. This is the only solution. But cacheEvict is also of NO USE if List update frequency is too hight, which in my case is.